# How to resolve Image not found java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, image, file

I'm giving input image to File for some purpose I stored Image and source file in same package but why I'm getting this error please help me ...
my package is `xyz` and source file name `image.java` and image is stored in `xyz/original.png`(i.e. Image path), below is code snip of image.java...

```
File file = new File("original.png");
try {
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);
}
```

[image: My directory structure]

Comment: Place your file parallel to xyz

Comment: Put image file in project folder

Comment: This is relative to the folder from where you run the application. So put the file there. Another approach, provide a full path (though not recommended)

Comment: my source flie image.java and original.png is in same directory xyz !!

Comment: You should have the image in `bin` folder - folder where you have your `.class` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot on stack overflow sites I found the solution and that is I placed my image may be in wrong directory :(
using

```
String file_name = "original.png";
        File file = new File(file_name);
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

I printed canonical path and this shows me that my image must be inside that path, After copying image at that path my code executed... thank you for your cooperation in resolving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream input = classname.class.getResourceAsStream("IMAGE FILE");
```

try using above approach to load the file . just pass the file name if its in the same package.

Comment: InputStream input = Class.class.getResourceAsStream("original.png");
System.out.println(input); when I print this ... and what can I do, can I pass this input to File file = new File("original.png");???

Comment: check the name of the file this wont throw `filenotfound exception` if the file doesnt exist.

Comment: Check out my question I edited and added image of my directory structure